# Angular Material - Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to patch my form with the existing date object, but that date "object" is saved in Firebase as a string :

```
date: "2017-09-05T21:00:00.000Z"
```

I console.log date when I submit the form and see it appear as:

```
Thu Sep 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

So AFAIK I must convert it to that shape before patching the form. How do I do that? Especially "Thu Sep" confuses me. Also note, that I will use different languages in the Datepicker.

**UPDATE**:

Looks like I managed to make the Date object, but it's value is very wrong:

```
  const str: string[] = this.initialValue.dateFrom.split('-');
  console.log(str); // ["2017", "08", "31T21:00:00.000Z"] - correct date
  const day = str[2][0] + str[2][1];
  console.log(day); // 31 - correct

  this.initialValue.dateFrom = new Date(+day, +str[1], +str[0]);
  console.log(this.initialValue.dateFrom); // Tue Mar 09 1937 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET) -  not correct.
```

Comment: Try `new Date(this.initialValue.dateFrom).toISOString()`

Comment: @Swoox - thanks, but no changes

Comment: Wait what format are you trying to get?

Comment: I am trying now. Maybe your method works, just need to use it correctly. I need format `Thu Sep 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)`

Comment: EDIT at the start `new date(this.initialValue.dateFrom)` should work fine tbh.

Comment: @Swoox  - :-) Thanks, worked like a charm!

Comment: Your more then welcome

Comment: @Swoox Feel free to post an answer :-)

Comment: I'm not here to collect points just to help :)

Comment: But I get two points then :DDD

Comment: But if without joking, so I think its best to close this topic + you get some points, so later could spend for bounty. I consider it almost as money - money to hire programmers :-)

Comment: Yeah it's the point of stackoverflow but I will earn more points one way or the other :P ty

Comment: I bet you will :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish.

Change this:

```
  const str: string[] = this.initialValue.dateFrom.split('-');
  console.log(str); // ["2017", "08", "31T21:00:00.000Z"] - correct date
  const day = str[2][0] + str[2][1];
  console.log(day); // 31 - correct

  this.initialValue.dateFrom = new Date(+day, +str[1], +str[0]);
```

Into:

```
new date(this.initialValue.dateFrom);
```